# Embulk: ignores last record value using incremental data with multiple primary key

Tags: java, oracle

Why embulk skips a last record value?

Is there a workaround?

Case: a wrong table

```
exec:<omit>
in:
  type: oracle
{% include 'inc/oracle_axlink' %}  # connection info
  query: |
    SELECT CTOIAWASE_NO, CTOIAWASE_YY, NSYDN_ORDER
    FROM TEST.TABLE1
    WHERE CTOIAWASE_NO >= :CTOIAWASE_NO
    AND   CTOIAWASE_YY >= :CTOIAWASE_YY
    AND   NSYDN_ORDER >= :NSYDN_ORDER
  use_raw_query_with_incremental: true
  incremental_columns: [ CTOIAWASE_NO, CTOIAWASE_YY, NSYDN_ORDER ]
  incremental: true
  last_record: [ "00100002", "2020", 1 ]
  options: {characterEncoding: MS932, characterSetResults: MS932,serverTimezone: JST}
  fetch_rows: 10000
  default_column_options:
     NUMERIC: { value_type: long }
     DECIMAL: { value_type: long }
out:<omit>
```

Error

```
\$ embulk run test.yml.liquid -c test_diff.yml.liquid
2022-10-13 15:51:59.959 +0900: Embulk v0.9.23
2022-10-13 15:52:01.231 +0900 [WARN] (main): DEPRECATION: JRuby org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer is directly injected.
2022-10-13 15:52:04.168 +0900 [INFO] (main): Gem's home and path are set by default: "/home/dbdevelop/.embulk/lib/gems"
2022-10-13 15:52:07.121 +0900 [INFO] (main): Started Embulk v0.9.23
2022-10-13 15:52:07.323 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-oracle (0.9.3)
2022-10-13 15:52:07.428 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-s3_parquet (0.5.2)
2022-10-13 15:52:07.527 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Connecting to jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX:1521/TEST options {oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=1800000, user=XXXXXX, serverTimezone=JST, password=***, characterEncoding=MS932, oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300000, characterSetResults=MS932}
2022-10-13 15:52:08.025 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Using JDBC Driver 12.1.0.2.0
2022-10-13 15:52:08.109 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Using local thread executor with max_threads=1 / tasks=1
2022-10-13 15:52:08.565 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): === Output Parquet Schema ===
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): message embulk {
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction):   optional binary CTOIAWASE_NO (STRING);
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction):   optional binary CTOIAWASE_YY (STRING);
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction):   optional int64 NSYDN_ORDER;
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): }
2022-10-13 15:52:08.566 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): =============================
2022-10-13 15:52:08.584 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): {done:  0 / 1, running: 0}
2022-10-13 15:52:08.884 +0900 [WARN] (0017:task-0000): Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2022-10-13 15:52:09.016 +0900 [INFO] (0017:task-0000): Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
2022-10-13 15:52:09.347 +0900 [INFO] (0017:task-0000): Local Buffer File: /tmp/embulk-output-s3_parquet-12345678912345/embulk-output-s3_parquet-task-0-0.parquet, Destination: s3://testtesttest-1234567890/append/test/table1.snappy.parquet
2022-10-13 15:52:09.403 +0900 [INFO] (0017:task-0000): Connecting to jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521/TEST options {oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=1800000, user=XXXXXXX, serverTimezone=JST, password=***, characterEncoding=MS932, oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300000, characterSetResults=MS932}
2022-10-13 15:52:09.455 +0900 [INFO] (0017:task-0000): SQL: SELECT CTOIAWASE_NO, CTOIAWASE_YY, NSYDN_ORDER
FROM TEST.TABLE1
WHERE CTOIAWASE_NO >= ?
AND   CTOIAWASE_YY >= :CTOIAWASE_YY
AND   NSYDN_ORDER >= ?

2022-10-13 15:52:09.455 +0900 [INFO] (0017:task-0000): Parameters: ["2020", 1]
2022-10-13 15:52:09.703 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): {done:  1 / 1, running: 0}
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: INまたはOUTパラメータがありま せん - 索引:: 3
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:340)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:566)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:353)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:22)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:242)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:291)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:155)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:431)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:90)
        at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: INまたはOUTパラメータがありません - 索引:: 3
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.run(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:509)
        at org.embulk.spi.util.Executors.process(Executors.java:62)
        at org.embulk.spi.util.Executors.process(Executors.java:38)
        at org.embulk.exec.LocalExecutorPlugin$DirectExecutor$1.call(LocalExecutorPlugin.java:170)
        at org.embulk.exec.LocalExecutorPlugin$DirectExecutor$1.call(LocalExecutorPlugin.java:167)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: INまたはOUTパラメータがありません - 索引:: 3
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2076)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4790)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.JdbcInputConnection$SingleSelect.fetch(JdbcInputConnection.java:194)
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.fetch(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:571)
        at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.run(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:480)
        ... 8 more

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: INまたはOUTパラメータがありません - 索引:: 3
```

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: INまたはOUTパラメータがありません - 索引:: 3
is 
Error: org.embulk.spi.DataException: Converting last_record value 1 to column index 2 is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to answer but could you try this;

```
 in:
   type: oracle
   ...
   column_options:
     CTOIAWASE_NO: { value_type: long }
     CTOIAWASE_YY: { value_type: long }
     NSYDN_ORDER: { value_type: long }
```

(Assuming that those columns are numeric)